# Cannot find image in table in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

Can anyone help, I cannot find an image in table with my javascript and if it finds it should browse to another webpage. And how can I see the println output in  Intellij, because I didn't find any output associated with println.

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='http://m.com/en/images/common/green_check.png']"));

        Boolean ImagePresent = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript
                        (
                                "return arguments[0].complete && type of arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0", image
                        );

        if (!ImagePresent)
        {
            System.out.println("Image isn't displayed.");
        }
        else
        {

            driver.get("https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=RkXaWNSpIeXJXrnZgYAL&gws_rd=ssl");
        }
```

The html is here:

```
<tr>
        <td> Does this Person do the home assignments? </td>
        <td class = "span1 tdTextAlignCenter">
            <img class='imageHeight' src='http://m.com/en/images/common/green_check.png' />         </td>
        <td class = "span1 tdTextAlignCenter">
                    </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/img[@src='http://m.com/en/images/common/green_check.png']"));

if(image.isDisplayed())
{
    System.out.println("Image is present on the page.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Image is not present on the page.");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wanted ask one more question regarding searching for a certain keyword in .txt file and this file is in internet. Can you please tell me, how I can search for a keyword in this file, which is on web? I have tried with this one, but it didn't work:  driver.getPageSource().equals("BACKGROUND")